# Delete the number of columns of a JTable

Tags: java, swing

Do you know if it's possible to edit a Jtable which has 6 columns ?

```
column = jTableMus.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column.setPreferredWidth(50);
        column = jTableMus.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        column.setPreferredWidth(150);
        column = jTableMus.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        column.setPreferredWidth(100);
        column = jTableMus.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        column.setPreferredWidth(80);
        column = jTableMus.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        column.setPreferredWidth(50);
        column = jTableMus.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
```

In fact, I would like to know how to change on 4 columns instead of 6 columns.

Thank for your answers.

Comment: Simply remove the columns from the `TableColumnModel` of the `JTable`.  See the [JavaDocs for `TableColumnModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I don't see where it is... It's in "propertie" then "model" ?? To delete several columns ?

Comment: `JTable#getColumnModel#removeColumn`

Comment: @ MadProgrammer : thank you my problem is resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control which columns are editable you can override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the `TableModel`.

So to make only the first 4 columns editable you could do something like:

```
@Override
public Boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
{
    return (column < 4) ? true : false;
}
```

Edit:

> I would like to delete 2 columns

A couple of different ways. You can delete the columns using:

1. `getColumn(...)` and `removeColumn(...)` methods from `JTable` API.
2. `getColumn(...)` and `removeColumn(...)` methods from `TableColumnModel` API

The approach you use will depend on whether you want to remove a column based on its index or its column name.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to delete 2 columns in fact it's possible?
For now I have 6 columns example id; name, firstname; date, sex, country;
I want to conserve id, name, firstname, date